# How to prove directly from the definition that the complex norm isn't differentiable at any point?

Tags: complex-analysis

> How to prove directly from the definition that the complex norm isn't differentiable at any point?

I used both ways of the definition:

$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{|z|-|z_0|}{z-z_0} \ \text{ and }\ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|z_0+h|-|z_0|}{h}$$

but I don't even know how to begin.

Comment: I think you did not mean derivable, but differentiable

Comment: @qbert it is okay, it happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z_0 = 0$, then since $t \mapsto |t|$ is not differentiable at $t=0$ we see that $z \mapsto |z|$ is not differentiable at $z_0=0$ .

If $z_0 \neq 0$ then  we have
$\lim_{r \to0} {|z_0+rz_0| - |z_0| \over r z_0}= {|z_0| \over z_0}$,
$\lim_{r \to0}{|z_0+riz_0| - |z_0| \over r iz_0}= 0$, hence
${|z_0+h| - |z_0| \over h}$ has no limit as $h \to 0$.

**Aside**: ${|z_0+riz_0| - |z_0| \over r iz_0} = {(|1+ri| - 1)|z_0| \over r iz_0} = {(|1+ri| - 1) \over r } \cdot {|z_0| \over iz_0} = {(\sqrt{1+r^2} - 1) \over r } \cdot {|z_0| \over iz_0} $. Note that ${(\sqrt{1+r^2} - 1) \over r } \to 0$.

Comment: Why the second limit is $|z_0|/iz_0$? I've tried to simplify but I can't get to that, I obtained $lim_{r->0}\frac{i(1-|1+ri|)}{r}$.

Comment: @AarónDavidArroyoTorres: Sorry, I made a mistake. I have fixed it above.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, for $z\ne0$ and $h\ne0$,
$$
\frac{|z+h|-|z|}{h}=\frac{|z|}{z}\frac{|1+(h/z)|-1}{h/z}
$$
so it's not restrictive to show that
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|1+h|-1}{h}
$$
doesn't exist. If it exists, then it's the same along every path. For $h$ real we have
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{|1+h|-1}{h}=1
$$
For $h=it$ with $t$ real,
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{|1+it|-1}{it}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sqrt{1+t^2}-1}{it}=0
$$
Do similarly at $z=0$.

---

More generally, if $f$ is defined on a region in $\mathbb{C}$ and only assumes real values, it can only be differentiable at points where
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}=0
$$
because the limit must be both real ($h$ approaching $0$ on the real axis) and purely imaginary ($h$ approaching $0$ on the imaginary axis).